# How can i check downloaded images in kubernetes(I'm using image in kubernetes yaml file)? Or, what is similar to 'docker images' cmd in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

How can i check downloaded images in kubernetes(I'm using image in kubernetes yaml file)?

Or, to be precise we can check downloaded docker image file with 'docker images' cmd. Do we have similar cmd in kubernetes to check the downloaded image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent command. The kubelet downloads images on demand, but really it just passes those commands on to the underlying system so to check which images are actually resident, you would need to know what CRI plugin you are using and talk to that. In general you don’t worry much about images in Kubernetes, they are automatically managed by the kubelet for you.